# Get product details data from an eBay API

Tags: ebay-api

I have eBay product IDs and I'm trying to find an API that will allow me to fetch all the details like that are found here:

http://cgi1.sandbox.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?PageSyiProductDetails&IncludeAttributes=1&ShowAttributesTable=1&ProductMementoString=124653:2:19518:3454066566:829316136:4873a90a9e8268f36b6acd1f9a5eef8f:1:1:1:5000070104565

It appears there is a database containing this sort of information, but I can't find anything but this HTML version.

NOTE: this is not about individual auction listings, but about product-level details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @skb you could use GetItem eBay API call to get item's data http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html

Comment: @keyur: that is for an individual auction, not a product.  the product wouldn't have seller information, price, or anything like that.  it's just metadata about the product itself.

Comment: The URL you linked looks like the <DetailsURL> response from the Shopping API version of FindProducts http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html

Comment: @skb, have you found a solution? I'm also stuck with that

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this @skb? I'm trying to do the same myself using http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/product/CallRef/getProductDetails.html

Thing is, I'm not sure which API service this is part of! Any ideas?